# How to require a js package in Laravel 5.5 project when using bower dependency Management tool?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, npm, bower

I have a project based on Laravel 5.5. In this project, I want to add  [tempusdominus bootstrap-3 datetimepicker](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-3/Installing/). Since this package does not have `npm` installer, I installed `bower` then installed it like so

```
npm install -g bower
bower init
bower install tempusdominus-core#latest --save
```

Now the package is installed in a `bower_components` folder of my Laravel project. However, I am unable to require this package into my app.js file.

```
window.datetimepicker = require('tempusdominus/core');
window.datetimepicker = require('eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker');
window.datetimepicker = require('/bower_components/tempusdominus-core/build/js/core.min.js');
```

I tried requiring the package using the following but Laravel Mix keeps failing to compile and gives me the following error

> This dependency was not found:
>   * /bower_componenets/tempusdominus-core/build/js/core.min.js

This is how I run Laravel-Mix

```
npm run watch
```

How can I successfully require a package that was installed via bower into Laravel Mix?

Comment: I think you are little confused with `require` in NodeJS runtime, you have no `require` by default in the client side, you need libs like requirejs.org to accomplish this

Comment: I may be confused yes. the app.js file in laravel get compiled using Laravel Mix which generates a client side js file. Here is how I am including other packages in my app.js file `window.validator = require('jquery-validation');
window.moment = require('moment-timezone');` which is working because these packages are installed using `npm` not `bower`

Comment: look on this please https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-bower